# How to access the meaning of a OID variable (Linux)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp

I am using `snmpwalk` to derive a subtree of management values. One of the lines reads, for example,

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5.0 = Gauge32: 10
```

but what does it mean? What device/function, ... corresponds to the OID `iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5.0`, and what does the number '10' stand for?

How to find out completly general for ANY OID (not just for this exemplary one)?

Comment: Well, iso is assigned the number 1, so http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5 , you seem to have 10 user sessions. However - stackoverflow.com is for programming questions - this question is better suited elsewhere.

Comment: @nos: Thanks, I was not aware of this site. I posted a similar question 6 hours ago on superuser, but it seem stackoverflow is at least 70 times faster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `snmptranslate` command:

```
$ snmptranslate iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5.0
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemNumUsers.0
```

Or you can do the lookup in reverse with `-On`:

```
$ snmptranslate -On HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemNumUsers.0
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5.0
```

*(Note that the `iso.` in the first look-up means the same as the `.1.` that the reverse translate shows)*

As noted in the comments, yes, you need the MIB installed in order to do these lookups, see your device vendor for the MIB file download. From what I've seen with a generic install of net-snmp, you get most of what you already are looking for.

Comment: Because there is MIB file available /usr/share/snmp/mibs/HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.txt

Answer (score 0):

`iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5.0`  OID provide number of logged in Users info.

`Gauge32` is OID type, Gauge32 you can expect the data increases and decreases based on what real world information it tries to provide

`10` means number of users currently logged in your system.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant how to answer this question for ANY OID, not just for the given example.

Comment: There is no single database for all OID because its vendor specific. You have to go and look into whatever vendor website and ask them to provide MIBs file.